# Auto change owner process builder

Tags: process-builder

I want auto change owner when I upadate status or comment in case.

I search: Next, add an immediate action to update the record that started the process, with field update as Owner Id/Field Reference/[Opportunity].Account.OwnerId.

But I don't see Account.OwnerId.

Comment: If you want to update OwnerId of the Case, then use [Case].Account.OwnerId